# Render Object Data in individual Cards with React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, arrayobject, mapping

I am trying to render data from an array of objects into multiple cards however React is only rendering the data from the first Object on the page. What are methods to do this?

```
const dogData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Hollie",
        breed: "Doberman",
        age: 3,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Charles",
        breed: "Golden Retriever",
        age: 4,

    }
]

export default dogData
```

```
import React from "react";
import dogData from "./dogData";

function DogCardsDisplayed() {
  for (let i = 0; i < dogData.length; i++) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>{dogData[i].name}</div>
        <div>{dogData[i].breed}</div>
        <div>{dogData[i].age}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

function SearchPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DogCardsDisplayed />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct way to render array.

1. always use map.
2. do not forget to have key for each item

```
function DogCardsDisplayed() {
    return dogData.map(item=> (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <div>{item.name}</div>
        <div>{item.breed}</div>
        <div>{item.age}</div>
      </div>
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your answer :

```
function DogCardsDisplayed(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(props.dog).map((key) => (
        <div>{dog[key]}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function SearchPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      {dogData.map((dog) => (
        <DogCardsDisplayed content={dog} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```